# Technology stack for keep-alive web site

Tags: ajax, web-applications, keep-alive

The most common technology stack for websites is Lamp, partly because it's available everywhere, and partly because the programming model is so simple: every request to the server generates a single call to the code and a single chunk of HTML sent back.

But consider the requirements for a Web program that needs keep-alive functionality, a continuous live stream of data to a Javascript front-end. The impression I get from e.g. ["Connection: Keep-Alive" in server response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991386/connection-keep-alive-in-server-response), http://ajaxian.com/archives/mibbit-ajax-based-irc-client and http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/12/are-php-persistent-connections-evil/ is that Lamp is just not designed for this type of workload.

So my question is, for a keep-alive workload (is that the best terminology?), what's the best technology stack?

Or to be more precise, what's the best stack by the criteria of *reliability*, *scalability* (I don't care about saving a few CPU cycles, but I do care about not getting into a situation where the thing falls over when you add a few more users, even on good high-end hardware) and *ubiquity* (being able to get started on cheap GoDaddy style hosting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) is designed for this sort of workload, it's fast and scales well for this type of workload (much faster than LAMP with AJAX calls back to apache/mod_php + mysql).  There are already a decent number of libraries and even some frameworks already out there for it, but there isn't a reason you can't mix and match lamp with node depending on your requirements.